# Getting IndexError: list index out of range trying to translate a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to work this python script out which help me translate a file based on stable prefixes.

error output :

```
G:\LocaleStringTranslator-master>py main.py
['', '[%s±ºAÖ] : %s  º,A_±Y_x %lld ', ';\n']
['\n']
['', '[TEST_ONLY]ÇöAç ±1°í : %d ', ';\n']
['\n']
['', '<±æµå> %d ½ºÅ3A» »ç¿ëÇO (%d, %d) to %lu', ';\n']
['\n']
['', '<±æµå> ÄdÅ,AOAI 3¡3ªAö _E_Æ ±æµå ½ºÅ3A» »ç¿ëÇO ¼ö _o½A'I'U.', ';\n']
['\n']
['', '<±æµå> %luAÇ °æÇèÄ¡,▌ ÅoAUÇI¿'½A'I'U.', ';\n']
['\n']
['', '<±æµå> %luAÇ ¿ë½Å·AA» E,º1ÇI¿'½A'I'U.', ';\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    key = line[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

main.py file:

```
toTranslate = {}
translationBase = {}

key = None

toTranslateFile = "toTranslate.txt"
translationBaseFile = "translationBase.txt"
resultFile = open("result.txt", "w")
otherFile = open("other.txt", "w")


with open(toTranslateFile, "r") as toTranslateFile:
    for line in toTranslateFile:
        if line != "" or line != "\n":
            if key == None:
                line = line.split('"')
                print(line)
                if len(line) >= 2:
                    key = line[1]
            else:
                toTranslate[key] = line
                key = None

with open(translationBaseFile, "r") as translationBaseFile:
    for line in translationBaseFile:
        if line != "":
            if key == None:
                line = line.split('"')
                key = line[1]
            else:
                translationBase[key] = line[1:-3]
                key = None


for key in toTranslate:
    if key in translationBase:
        resultFile.write('"' + key + '"\n"' + translationBase[key] + '";\n\n')
    else:
        otherFile.write('"' + key + '"\n"' + toTranslate[key] + '";\n\n')
```

translationBase.txt: 
https://pastebin.com/uij621P2

toTranslate.txt:
https://pastebin.com/DG77KVkz

Comment: Hi Jeff, you have this check :  if len(line) >= 2: in the first chunk of code at line18- do you want it in the second chunk as well, just before key = line[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over all lines, which includes an empty line. Here's a solution:

```py
toTranslate = {}
translationBase = {}

key = None

toTranslateFile = "toTranslate.txt"
translationBaseFile = "translationBase.txt"
resultFile = open("result.txt", "w")
otherFile = open("other.txt", "w")


with open(toTranslateFile, "r") as toTranslateFile:
    for line in toTranslateFile:
        if line != "" or line != "\n":
            if key == None:
                line = line.split('"')
                print(line)
                if len(line) >= 2:
                    key = line[1]
            else:
                toTranslate[key] = line
                key = None

with open(translationBaseFile, "r") as translationBaseFile:
    for line in translationBaseFile:
        if line == "\n": # Blank line
            continue # Break out of the loop
        if line != "":
            if key == None:
                line = line.split('"')
                key = line[1]
            else:
                translationBase[key] = line[1:-3]
                key = None


for key in toTranslate:
    if key in translationBase:
        resultFile.write('"' + key + '"\n"' + translationBase[key] + '";\n\n')
    else:
        otherFile.write('"' + key + '"\n"' + toTranslate[key] + '";\n\n')
```

This was causeing issues because you were splitting by `"`, but the empty line is simply a newline (`\n`). This means the array is `['\n']`, and you're trying to access a non-existent second item. This causes an `IndexError`.